# Python/Django - not access to linked model in a generic view

Tags: python, django, self

I'm newbie in Python and Django
I've 3 models linked: patient -> visit -> prescription

I want to override get_context_data in a detailView to have access to all prescription related to patient
visit to patient related_name = 'visits'
prescription to visit related_name = 'prescriptions'

but I have an error:

> PatientFile object has no attribute 'visits'

I look what is inside self:

> patient.views.PatientFile object at 0x04772EB0

I don't understand
self is my patient instance so I should have access to all visits with attribute 'visits'?

```
class PatientFile(DetailView):

    model = Patient
    context_object_name = "patient"
    template_name = "patient/file.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['prescriptions'] = []
    print('self : ', self)
    for visit in self.visits:
        context['prescriptions'].append(visits.prescriptions)
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

The `self` in your `DetailView` is the `PatientFile` view object, not the `Patient` object.

You can however access the `Patient` object with [**`self.object`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView):

```
class PatientFile(DetailView):

    model = Patient
    context_object_name = 'patient'
    template_name = 'patient/file.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['prescriptions'] = prescriptions = []
        for visit in self.object.visits.all():
            prescriptions.extend(visit.prescriptions.all())
        return context
```

Note that in order to iterate over a relation, you should use `.all()`, not just `self.visits`.

Comment: I did not really understand context['prescriptions'] = prescriptions = [] double affectation?

Comment: @SLATER: we assign the list `[]` to both the `context['prescriptions']` and a variable `prescriptions`. This makes it easier to just work with `prescriptions` in the `for` loop.

Comment: I got access to my 'prescriptions' context in my template but i did not manage to iterate on it : [<Prescription: Type 1 / 1457>, <Prescription: None / 1457>, <Prescription: None / 1457>] ; it is effectively a list (i test the type) and I can get value with prescriptions.0.prp_id for example but if I try to iterate {% for prescription in prescriptions %} it does not work or {% for prescription in prescriptions.all %}  I have an error

Comment: @SLATER: how do you iterate over it? Can you include (relevant) parts of your template in the *question*?

Comment: {% for prescription in prescriptions.all %}
            prescription.prp_com
{% endfor %}

Comment: @SLATER: ah, but `prescriptions` is a list, so it is `{% for prescription in prescriptions %}`.

Comment: i try this but I had an error on line I had commented... if I suppress the commented line it works... thanks a lot Willem for your time